# Turn on Swap after resize /

Tags: lvm, swap

I resized with lvresize the swap from 4 to 2G and can't  turn it on.

```
swapon /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
swapon: /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap: swapon failed: Invalid argument

lvdisplay /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
  VG Name                VolGroup
  LV UUID                h7DEfK-cdVr-UzeQ-8qDJ-rAhH-ejYS-k2wyY6
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                2.06 GiB
  Current LE             66
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `mkswap` on that device:

```
# mkswap /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
```

Resizing the device will not, by itself, re-prepare the device for swapping.